# Pieces not being removed when taken

Tags: java, arraylist, chess

I am creating a Chess Game and I just finished the basic Ai, but whenever a piece is taken it disappears and comes back a few turns later. The piece shouldn't even be in the list that renders the pieces. 
This is the class that render/adds/sets the new pieces

`setPieceLoc()` sets the old piece at its new location and removes both the `original` and the `newLoc` from all lists.
Does anyone see why this is happening? There is no other class that adds new information to the lists, so as far as I can tell it must be an error here.

```
package me.xthegamerplayz.FirstGame.board;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import me.xthegamerplayz.FirstGame.board.tiles.ChessImages;
import me.xthegamerplayz.FirstGame.rules.LegalMoves;

public class Board {

    public static void addPiece(int x, int y, int piece) {

        Point point = new Point();
        point.setLocation(x, y);

        if(piece > 16)
            ChessBoard.black.put(point, piece);
        else
            ChessBoard.white.put(point, piece);
    }

    public static void setPieceLoc(Point original, Point newLoc) {
        int piece = 8;
        if(ChessBoard.white.containsKey(original))
            piece = ChessBoard.white.get(original);
        else if(ChessBoard.black.containsKey(original))
            piece = ChessBoard.black.get(original);

        //Remove piece at newLoc
        if(ChessBoard.white.containsKey(newLoc))
            ChessBoard.white.remove(newLoc);
        else if(ChessBoard.black.containsKey(newLoc))
            ChessBoard.black.remove(newLoc);

        //Remove piece from previous location
        if(ChessBoard.white.containsKey(original))
            ChessBoard.white.remove(original);
        else if(ChessBoard.black.containsKey(original))
            ChessBoard.black.remove(original);

        if(piece > 16)
            ChessBoard.black.put(newLoc, piece);
        else
            ChessBoard.white.put(newLoc, piece);
    }

    public void registerPieces() {
        //Pawns
        for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            addPiece(x, 1, 8);
            addPiece(x, 6, 24);
        }
        //White
        addPiece(0, 0, 9);
        addPiece(1, 0, 10);
        addPiece(2, 0, 11);
        addPiece(5, 0, 11);
        addPiece(6, 0, 10);
        addPiece(7, 0, 9);

        addPiece(4, 0, 12);
        addPiece(3, 0, 13);

        //Black
        addPiece(0, 7, 25);
        addPiece(1, 7, 26);
        addPiece(2, 7, 27);
        addPiece(5, 7, 27);
        addPiece(6, 7, 26);
        addPiece(7, 7, 25);

        addPiece(3, 7, 28);
        addPiece(4, 7, 29);

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {

        for(Point point : ChessBoard.white.keySet()) {

            int piece = ChessBoard.white.get(new Point(point));
            int x = (int) (point.getX()*64) + 20;
            int y = (int) (point.getY()*64) + 20;

            boolean showTiles = false;
            if(showTiles) {
                if(piece == 24) {
                    LegalMoves lm = new LegalMoves(point);

                    for(Point p : lm.moves()) {

                        int bx = (int) (p.getX()*64) + 20;
                        int by = (int) (p.getY()*64) + 20;
                        g.setColor(Color.green);
                        g.fillRect(bx, by, 64, 64);
                    }
                }
            }

            g.drawImage(ChessImages.getPieceImage(piece), x, y, null);
        }

        for(Point point : ChessBoard.black.keySet()) {

            int piece = ChessBoard.black.get(new Point(point));
            int x = (int) (point.getX()*64) + 20;
            int y = (int) (point.getY()*64) + 20;

            boolean showTiles = false;
            if(showTiles) {
                if(piece == 24) {
                    LegalMoves lm = new LegalMoves(point);

                    for(Point p : lm.moves()) {

                        int bx = (int) (p.getX()*64) + 20;
                        int by = (int) (p.getY()*64) + 20;
                        g.setColor(Color.green);
                        g.fillRect(bx, by, 64, 64);
                    }
                }
            }

            g.drawImage(ChessImages.getPieceImage(piece), x, y, null);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can I suggest posting your code in the question rather than a link to code, your more likely to get help that way

Comment: paste relevant code instead of image..

Comment: It is a bit to post and its not an image, but ok

Comment: Recommend posting an [mcve]

Comment: Does this piece happen to always be piece #8 (whatever that happens to be)?  I can see this happening if you're moving from an empty square.

Comment: Well Piece 8 is a white pawn and it seems to center around a pawn actually. I don't see how it can be caused when moving from an empty square because halfway through the game it seems to happen. Also it is only triggered when taking a piece or being taken

Comment: @JoeC Here is a video of it happening. It happens at 22-27. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHmn2wWjbwk&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to make a move a piece from somewhere that is empty.

Note that, when your original is in neither the black nor white maps, it will use piece 8, which appears to be a white pawn.  That happens to be the piece reappearing in your video.

You should really be throwing an exception when this happens, because moving a piece from an empty square makes no sense.  Doing this should help you debug the circumstance in which this is happening:

```
if(ChessBoard.white.containsKey(original))
    piece = ChessBoard.white.get(original);
else if(ChessBoard.black.containsKey(original))
    piece = ChessBoard.black.get(original);
else
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attempting to move piece from empty square " + original);
```

Comment: I did so and it is being thrown, but it shouldn't as the AI should never be able to grab a location that isn't listed. Here is the AI

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't.  But it clearly is.  I suggest putting a breakpoint where that exception is thrown and running through a debugger.